# Use prestashop Mail::Send in external PHP file

Tags: php, rest, prestashop-1.6

i trying to use Prestashop Mail::Send in external php file (Our API endpoint)
I tryied include config.inc.php, init.php also. It looks like API working with PHP mail functions. But presta have Mail class, other Prestashop classes works correctly.
I have Prestashop 1.6.1.9 and PHP 5.6

I have code:

```
class VoucherModel extends baseModel{

// Other methods
public function addSubscriber($email)
{
    $result = Db::getInstance()->insert("mail_subscribers", array(
      "email" => pSQL($email)
    ));

    if($result){

      $cartRule = "XYZ123";
      $sendMail = $this->_sendMail($email, $cartRule);

      return $sendMail;
    }
}

public function _sendMail($email, $code = "LOVEMANA")
{
  $templateVars['{code}'] = $code;
  $id_land = Language::getIdByIso('cs');
  $template_name = 'sendvoucher';
  $title = 'Váše kredity';
  $from = Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL');
  $fromName = Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME');
  $mailDir = _PS_THEME_DIR_.'/mails/';

  return Mail::Send($id_land, $template_name, $title, $templateVars, $email, "", $from, $fromName);

}
}
```

But i getting error:

```
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Mail::send() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/models/prestashop.php on line 780
PHP message: PHP Stack trace:
PHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/index.php:0
PHP message: PHP   2. Luracast\\Restler\\Restler->handle() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/index.php:41
PHP message: PHP   3. Luracast\\Restler\\Restler->call() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/include/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:283
PHP message: PHP   4. call_user_func_array:{/home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/include/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:989}() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/include/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:989
PHP message: PHP   5. v1\\Api->subscribe() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/include/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:989
PHP message: PHP   6. prestashop->addSubscriber() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/v1/Api.php:1090
PHP message: PHP   7. prestashop->_sendMail() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/models/prestashop.php:764

PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail.php on line 117
PHP message: PHP Stack trace:
PHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/index.php:0
PHP message: PHP   2. Luracast\\Restler\\Restler->handle() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/index.php:41
PHP message: PHP   3. Luracast\\Restler\\Restler->call() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/include/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:283
PHP message: PHP   4. call_user_func_array:{/home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/include/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:989}() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/include/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:989
PHP message: PHP   5. v1\\Api->subscribe() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/include/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:989
PHP message: PHP   6. prestashop->addSubscriber() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/v1/Api.php:1090
PHP message: PHP   7. prestashop->_sendMail() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/models/prestashop.php:764
PHP message: PHP   8. Mail->send() /home/97569-75425.cloudwaysapps.com/axbxzqwhfd/public_html/obchod/mobileapiv2/models/prestashop.php:780
', referer: https://beta.drink-mana.com/en/
```

Other Prestashop classes work correctly. (Configuration::get, Product::getPriceStatic)

Answer (score 0):

Try to call this method non-statical.

If you have PHP 5.4+ try to use this code:

```
return (new Mail)->Send($id_land, $template_name, $title, $templateVars, $email, "", $from, $fromName);
```

Or if u have PHP < 5.4, try this:

```
$mail = new Mail();
return $mail->Send($id_land, $template_name, $title, $templateVars, $email, "", $from, $fromName);
```

Comment: Nothing, still getting: Deprecated: Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail.php on line 117

Comment: To remove this error you need go to file /usr/share/php/Mail.php and replace PEAR::raiseError to (new PEAR)->raiseError. I`m not shure but it can help.

Comment: i dont have permissions for do this.